# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function is seen when trying to obtain the code from the summernote

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, summernote

I am trying to obtain the code from one summernote(which has loaded fine) but I am facing the error mentioned in the title. You have a code snippet here:
In the body I have declare one of my summernotes like this:
`<div class="summernote1" name="intro_summer_note" id="intro_summer_note"></div>`

Then under the script tags I am trying the following:

```
                   $('.summernote1').summernote({
                    placeholder: 'Write your intro',
                    tabsize: 2,
                    height: 250,
                    toolbar: [
                      ['style', ['style']],
                      ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
                      ['color', ['color']],
                      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                      ['table', ['table']],
                      ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
                      ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
                    ]
                  }); 

                  function submitSummerNote()
                  {
                    console.log('Entered here')
                    var markupStr = $('.summernote1').summernote('code');
                    console.log(markupStr);
                  }
```

I have tried the examples from the summernote page and I am getting into the exactly same issue. I have also tried updating the jQuery version. Right now I am trying the following versions for jQuery and Bootstrap:
    `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are messing with positioning, i've launched the code and it ran without any problem, be sure to put both Bootstrap and jQuery before your script, like:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
<div class="summernote1" name="intro_summer_note" id="intro_summer_note"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.js">
 </script>
<script>
    $('.summernote1').summernote({
    placeholder: 'Write your intro',
    tabsize: 2,
    height: 250,
    toolbar: [
      ['style', ['style']],
      ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
      ['color', ['color']],
      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
      ['table', ['table']],
      ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
      ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
    ]
  }); 

  function submitSummerNote()
  {
    console.log('Entered here')
    var markupStr = $('.summernote1').summernote('code');
    console.log(markupStr);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This HTML is extending the base HTML: {% extends "core/base.html" %}
under the base HTML, I have the following in the head:
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.js"></script>

Comment: I can also see that the summernote and jquery has loaded fine under the Networking tab in the browser.